# How to keep CSS Hover and jQuery text/Input and container Open?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a search box built that operates pretty much exactly how I would like, except for one slight issue, that only part of solution is working. I've tried a few answers from here on "SO" and even gotten some ideas from here to put it all together, which I'm very grateful for, but I'm really stuck with it now.

The whole thing opens up from a font awesome icon after a CSS hover, this includes the "box" it's in and the input. I've got some jQuery to keep the box open until the user clicks away from it, however if the mouse is moved, i.e. the hover is taken away, then the text/input disappears (The box stays open). I would like the whole search box to stay open after the hover, including the text as well so it stays visible, even if the user moves the mouse away, and then for it all to close up when clicked away (or of course if the search is entered, but that's a whole other thing) I've gotten this far and I know I must be missing something relatively minor, so thank you for any help! Also if any of the code appears horribly wrong or could be improved, I'd very much appreciate any input!

`div.search-box:hover > input.search-txt` - This seems to be the main part of the CSS that's blowing my mind. I've tried moving the hover around etc, but the > doesn't seem to be working as I thought it should. I tried adding in or writing new jQuery for the "text input" similar to keeping the "box" open, but this CSS selector seems to be overriding it or something. I even tried adding a class on its own via jQuery but again it had the same problem. If I don't use this selector then I'm more or less back to square one.

I've added the basic code below and made a jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/g7vkc3x1/15/#&togetherjs=oRMrQkQlLD

HTML:

```
<div class="search-head">
                <div class="search-box">
                    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search...">
                        <a class="search-btn" href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
CSS:
.search-head {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 34px;
  min-width: 2.73%;
  transition: width 1s;
  border-radius: 80px;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: rgb(161, 161, 161);
}

div.search-box:hover,
.perm-hover {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
}

div.search-box:hover > input.search-txt { 
  width: 75%;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.search-btn {
  color: var(--clr-primary-1);
  float: right;
  width: 3.8em;
  height: 3.7em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-btn > i {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(0, 112, 177) !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

jQuery:

```
{
  $(".search-box").click(function () {
    $(".search-box").addClass("perm-hover");
  });

  $(".search-box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(function () {
    $(document).click(function () {
      $(".search-box").removeClass("perm-hover");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You can (should be able to) include a jsfiddle link *if* you *also* include the code in the question, which you have.  No need for dodgy work arounds like including a picture

Comment: The website said I wasn't allowed to put a link in and physically wouldn't let me.. Think its because my accounts too new or something :/ But has let me put it in the comment..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g7vkc3x1/15/#&togetherjs=oRMrQkQlLD

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for the update - we get a *lot* of questions that are just "see this fiddle"  with all sorts of dodgy work arounds to get passed the restriction.  Maybe it's changed.

Comment: No worries, I was pretty confused the first time I posted a question! But I've tried my best to include what I could think of and what it would let me. Genuinely very stuck with a genuine problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found your bug, your input hides again after you move your mouse away from it.
At this code

```
div.search-box:hover > input.search-txt {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

You should change it to:

```
div.search-box:hover > input.search-txt, div.search-box.perm-hover > input.search-txt {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

So when search box (parent) get's class of perm-hover it should extend css as hover on the input inside of it.

Comment: Amazing! You're a star! Thank you so much! I'd have either never come to this or probably still been at it next week! Amazing how narrow in thought I can get with little issues like this.